# PHP Regex Matching Image URLs

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching

This is my Image Url PHP Code.

$GetImage = 'https://lh6.ggpht.com/hWXw7YRl9DpSMewd29xT9rvxcgnmGXeXSY9FTaPc3cbBCa-JO8yfwSynmD5C1DLglw=w124';

preg_match_all("/https://\w\w\d.\w+.com/[\w-]+=\w\d{2,3}/", $GetImage, $Result, PREG_SET_ORDER);

its working for me, but i want to extract "[\w-]" pattern results, in other words, i want to extract "hWXw7YRl9DpSMewd29xT9rvxcgnmGXeXSY9FTaPc3cbBCa-JO8yfwSynmD5C1DLglw" this string from my image Url...

Please anybody help my to solve this problem....

thanks

Comment: Em, you _did_ read the documentation of `preg_match`? You _did_ try putting braces (`()`) around that `[\w-]+` sequence?

Comment: i will catch this string in $Result[0] ?

Comment: !! You _DID_ read the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel it's overkill to try to match the entire URL using a regular expression. I suggest you parse the URL first using PHP's built-in function [parse_url()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

```
<?php

$str = 'https://lh6.ggpht.com/hWXw7YRl9DpSMewd29xT9rvxcgnmGXeXSY9FTaPc3cbBCa-JO8yfwSynmD5C1DLglw=w124';

// Parse the URL before applying a regex. Only get the path part. Use substring to remove the leading slash
$path = substr( parse_url( $str, PHP_URL_PATH ), 1 );

$pattern = '/([^=]+)/';
$matches = array();

if ( preg_match( $pattern, $path, $matches ) ) {
    // Regex matched

    $id = $matches[1];

    // Outputs: string 'hWXw7YRl9DpSMewd29xT9rvxcgnmGXeXSY9FTaPc3cbBCa-JO8yfwSynmD5C1DLglw' (length=66)
    var_dump( $id );
}

?>
```

Note that the snippet does not check the domain name. You can easily adjust the script to do so by not limiting the [parse_url()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function to only return the path, but also the other parts.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$GetImage = 'https://lh6.ggpht.com/hWXw7YRl9DpSMewd29xT9rvxcgnmGXeXSY9FTaPc3cbBCa-JO8yfwSynmD5C1DLglw=w124';
preg_match_all('#https://.*\.com/([\w-]+=\w\d{2,3})#iU', $GetImage, $match, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($match);
```